# How to Implement a Product Filter in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

I'm a beginner in Spring Boot and I'm developing an API where I need to implement a product filtering functionality. The frontend will send product names in a comma-separated format. I will convert them and save them into a string array. Then, I need to retrieve details for only those products from MongoDB. The challenge lies in efficiently handling the retrieval process based on the received product names. After receiving the product names, I have to make a request to MongoDB and save the results in JSON or a POJO class.

```
private String entityId;
private String entityName;
private Integer totalTests;
private List<'ClassType'> childEntities;

private int productName_1;
private int productName_2;
.
.
.
private int productName_n;
```

Any help will be appreciated.

I am seeking guidance on how to efficiently implement a filter that will make requests to MongoDB for the required products only, based on the product names received in the request. Additionally, I need assistance in designing a mechanism to save the filtered results into either a JSON format or a POJO class field. Any insights or best practices on how to achieve this in Spring Boot with MongoDB would be greatly appreciated.

Final JSON should looks like :

```
{
    "entityId": "01",
    "entityName": "Test Entity Name",
    "totalTests": 0,
    
    "product_1": 0,
        "product_2": 0,
          .
          .
          .
        "product_N": 0,
    
    "childEntities": [
        {
            "entityId": "03",
        "entityName": "Test Entity Name2",
        "totalTests": 0,
            
        "product_1": 0,
        "product_2": 0,
              .
          .
          .
        "product_N": 0,
        "childEntities": []
        }
     ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To filter products based on names from MongoDB and return results as JSON in Spring Boot, follow these steps:

Parse Product Names: Convert the comma-separated product names into a list.

```
List<String> names = Arrays.asList(productNames.split(","));
```

Create MongoDB Repository Method: Define a method in your repository to find products by names.

```
List<Product> findByNameIn(List<String> names);
```

Fetch Products: Use the repository method to fetch the products.

```
List<Product> products = productRepository.findByNameIn(names);
```

Convert to Desired Structure: Create a map or a POJO to match your JSON structure and populate it with the fetched products.

Return JSON Response: Return the map or POJO as a response entity.

```
return ResponseEntity.ok(responseMap);
```

This approach requires a MongoDB model for your products, a repository interface extending MongoRepository, and a controller method to handle the request and response.

Hope it helps !

Comment: @Oxgotznit thankyou for your help , but what if there will N number products then I don't want to set details of product one by one ! any dynamic way for this ?

Comment: For handling N number of products dynamically, leverage MongoDB's aggregation framework or Spring Data's @Query annotation to filter directly in your query, reducing manual iteration. Use Spring's ResponseEntity to automatically convert your list or map of products to JSON. This approach minimizes code and efficiently handles variable product counts without explicitly setting each product's details. Something like this : List<Product> products = productRepository.findByNameIn(Arrays.asList(productNames.split(",")));
return ResponseEntity.ok(products);